# sql - return values from a column with multiple ids related to another table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 2 tables

question:

```
+-----------+-------------------------+
|question id|          help_ref       |
+-----------+-------------------------+
|     1     |      1001,1002,1004     |
+-----------+-------------------------+
|     2     |      1005,1002,1001     |
+-----------+-------------------------
```

help:

```
+--------------------+
|  id  |  text       |
+--------------------+
| 1001 | sjfdisfidif |
+--------------------+
| 1002 |  dfdjdjdjjd |
+--------------------+
| 1003 | blafdsjdidjd|
+--------------------+
| 1004 | somethibngjd|
+--------------------+
```

basically I want to join the data from the help table by using the help_ref column.
thank you

Comment: What's the expected result for this sample data?

Comment: If possible...normalize your data.... otherwise every query will be an uphill battle

Comment: MySQL provides `FIND_IN_SET` for unnormalized data (comma separated values) i never tryed a join with `FIND_IN_SET` as on statements. Maybe this works  `SELECT ... question JOIN help ON FIND_IN_SET(help.id, question.help_ref)` .. Keep in mind that if it works it never can use a index to speeds up the performance.

Comment: it works but im getting the value of the first one only